# What separators does the hive ngram UDF use to tokenize?

Tags: split, hive, nlp, sentiment-analysis, n-gram

I am performing some sentiment analysis.

I need to count the vocabulary (distinct words) in within a text.

The ngram UDF seems to do a great job at determining the unigrams. I want to know what separators it uses to determine the unigrams/ tokens. This is important if I want to mimic the vocabulary count using the split UDF instead. For example, given the following text (a product review)

> I was aboslutely shocked to see how much 1 oz really was. At $7.60, I mistakenly assumed it would be a decent sized can. As locally I am able to buy a medium sized tube of wasabi paste for around $3, but never used it fast enough so it would get old. I figured a powder would be better, so I can mix it as I needed it. When I opened the box and dug thru the packing and saw this little little can, I started looking for the hidden cameras ...  thought this HAD to be a joke. Nope .. and it's NOT returnable either. SO I HAVE LEARNED MY LESSON. Please just be aware if you should decide you want this EXPENSIVE wasabi powder.

The ngram UDG counts 82 unigrams/ tokens

```
SELECT count(*) FROM 
(SELECT explode(ngrams(sentences(upper(reviewtext)),1,9999999))  
FROM  amazon.Food_review_part_small WHERE asin = 'B0000CNU1X' AND reviewerid ='A1UCAVBNJUZMPR') t;
82
```

However, using the split UDF with space, comma, period, hyphen and double quotation marks as separators, there are 85 unigrams/tokens

```
select  count(distinct(te)) FROM amazon.Food_review_part_small 
lateral view explode(split(upper(reviewtext), '[\\s,.-]|\"')) t as te
WHERE te <> '' AND asin = 'B0000CNU1X' AND reviewerid ='A1UCAVBNJUZMPR';
85
```

Of course there is little to no documentation that i can find. Does anyone know what separators the ngram UDF uses to determine unigram tokens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the UDAF ngram does  not split the data, actually it already expect an array of string or an array of array of strings as input. The UDF [sentences](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFSentences.java) split the data in this case, From the java comments:

```
+ "Unnecessary punctuation, such as periods and commas in English, is automatically stripped."
+ " If specified, 'lang' should be a two-letter ISO-639 language code (such as 'en'), and "
+ "'country' should be a two-letter ISO-3166 code (such as 'us'). Not all country and "
+ "language codes are fully supported, and if an unsupported code is specified, a default "
```

If you run the following query

```
select sentences("I was aboslutely shocked to see how much 1 oz really was. At $7.60, I mistakenly assumed it would be a decent sized can. As locally I am able to buy a medium sized tube of wasabi paste for around $3, but never used it fast enough so it would get old. I figured a powder would be better, so I can mix it as I needed it. When I opened the box and dug thru the packing and saw this little little can, I started looking for the hidden cameras ... thought this HAD to be a joke. Nope .. and it's NOT returnable either. SO I HAVE LEARNED MY LESSON. Please just be aware if you should decide you want this EXPENSIVE wasabi powder.");
```

you will get the following result

```
[["I","was","aboslutely","shocked","to","see","how","much","1","oz","really","was"],["At","I","mistakenly","assumed","it","would","be","a","decent","sized","can"],["As","locally","I","am","able","to","buy","a","medium","sized","tube","of","wasabi","paste","for","around","but","never","used","it","fast","enough","so","it","would","get","old"],["I","figured","a","powder","would","be","better","so","I","can","mix","it","as","I","needed","it"],["When","I","opened","the","box","and","dug","thru","the","packing","and","saw","this","little","little","can","I","started","looking","for","the","hidden","cameras","thought","this","HAD","to","be","a","joke"],["Nope","and","it's","NOT","returnable","either"],["SO","I","HAVE","LEARNED","MY","LESSON"],["Please","just","be","aware","if","you","should","decide","you","want","this","EXPENSIVE","wasabi","powder"]]
```

as you can see, the udf sentences is removing some "noise" like "$7.60", "$3" as empty string as well.